# How to bind to the active ItemsControl item from a NESTED ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

This is driving me insane.
Maybe I have designed my data wrong, but I am trying to bind to the active item from a parent ItemsControl.

Every area gets a color so that its easily identied on screen. Instead of giving the color property to each seat, I planted the color in the Area model. All child seats need to use that color to paint themselves.

No matter what I try, I can not reach the parent ItemsControl so I can fetch the active color property for that specific area.

**Models (Simplified)**

```
public class BuildingLayout
{
    public ObservableCollection<Area> Areas { get; set; }
}

public class Area
{
    public Color Color { get; set; } // The color I want to bind to
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<Table> Tables { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    public int Seat { get; set; } // The seat needs to get the area color
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Areas}">
    ...
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- Nested Listbox -->
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tables}">
              ...
              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <!-- Now I want to get to the color property of
                           the parent (Area) -->
                      <Rectangle Fill="{Binding ..., Path=Color}" />
                  </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding DataContext.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
```

Because the nested `ItemsControl` is inside the `ItemTemplate` for the Parent one, therefore it will have the `Area` instance as it's DataContext.